# How do I force the SmartTable to load all items?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

My SAP UI5 view contains a [SmartTable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable%23overview) that is bound to an entity set in an ODataModel in read-only mode.

The table limits the number of items it displays to 100, verifiable by the `?$top=0&$limit=100` parameters it appends ot the data query to the server.

However, my users would like to have the table load and display *all* items, without paging or having to press some "More" button.

Is there a way to override the SmartTable's default behavior? For example by setting some `growingSize` property to "Infinity"? Or by modifying the aggregation binding? Or by adding annotations to the OData service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not specify the number of expected items or the table you're using here are some general considerations and a few possible solutions.

#### The type of table

There are a few things to consider between the varying types of tables you can use, there is some advice of SAP itself from the [design guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table/):

> Do not use the responsive table if: You expect the table to contain more than around 1,000 rows. Try using the analytical table or grid table instead; they are easier to handle, perform better, and are optimised for handling large numbers of items.

#### Ways around it

*First option* I can think of, if you're using a responsive table and you expect less than 1000 rows then the [scroll to load feature](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/api/sap.m.ListBase%23methods/getGrowingScrollToLoad) might be of interest which should load more entries when the user reaches the bottom of the current list.

There are ways to increase the default size of 100, both through the table using the [`growingThreshold`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/api/sap.m.ListBase%23methods/setGrowingThreshold) property, or through the declaration of the oData model using the [`sizeLimit`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/api/sap.ui.model.Model%23methods/setSizeLimit)

If you're using a grid table then the scroll-to-load works slightly differently, since it doesn't display all rows at the same time. Instead, it destroys the current lines to display new lines, which is why it's recommended for (very) large datasets.

*Second*, if none of those solutions work for your users you could alternatively first fetch the count of the current list including filters, so you can set an accurate threshold on the table before displaying results. If done correctly, your oData service should return a count using `/myserivce/MyEntity/$count?$filters...` when queried. CDS does this automatically, older services will need to implement that separately.

*Last*, if you know the list never exceeds a certain number of lines, you could set the `growingThreshold` parameter on the table to that number and then you don't have to worry about fetching an accurate count first.

How all of this is implemented depends a bit on how you create the smart table (elements, manually etc) so I'm not sure how to provide usable example code

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I intentionally didn't include source code because I was hoping for this exact kind of more general answer. My case is in fact a SmartTable with an included sap.m.Table with list binding to an OData aggregation. It's supposed to contain a little more than 100 entries, which makes paging for a handful of extra items look a little silly.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a `formatter` function which will return how many entries are within your model.

```
<SmartTable growingThreshold = "{path:'yourModel>/', formatter:'.formatter.sizeCalculator'}">
```

In the `formatter` File, which is usually to find in the model folder:

```
sizeCalcualtor: function(oModel){
  let count = 0;
  for(let i in oModel){
    //add item to count;
  }
return count;
}
```